# woocommerce integration not working

Tags: paypal, integration, payment, woocommerce, merchant-account

When I check out the products I wish to purchase from my store it directs me to Paypal's page and I need to log in to my paypal account in order to purchase the items. However, every time I try logging in it says "Please check your email address and password and try again" which is very concerning since it works when I log in through Paypal's website.

It is not set to a test account. And I have tried using various paypal accounts.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce is a great feature for Wordpress sites. I personally use the [MagicPay gateway](http://www.magicpay.net/virtual-terminal-payment-gateway-rates/) (see link if you want to check it out) with my online store, it integrates perfectly to my site and my customers don't have to have Paypal, they can just punch in their credit card numbers...

When I signed up they have a guy there who helped me with the integration.

Hope I helped!